# Convert Gradle Project to Neatbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, gradle

I need to convert my Gradle project to something that Netbeans is able to open **without any additional plugins**. I guess converting the Gradle files to Ant could be a possible solution but I have not found any informations about Gradle to Ant conversions.

Do you guys know a proper way to achieve my goal?

The reason for this mess is that I am developing with Gradle but my client uses Netbeans IDE and so he requires compatible project files. I personally would not like to switch to Netbeans, perhaps you may spare me the trouble. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as far as I have tried you have two options:

1. If you are using normal java project (not java EE) you can use
   [Netbeans Gradle plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44510/gradle-support). It works like a charm for normal java
   projects. But since you don't want to use plugins that is not an
   option.
2. I don't know about any gradle ant converter. And since Netbeans has awesome support for maven. You can convert gradle
   project to maven and the open maven project in Netbeans.

Just add new task to your build.gradle file. It should look something like this:

```
task writeNewPom << {
    pom {
        project {
            inceptionYear '2008'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("$buildDir/pom.xml")
}
```

You can
    find more details here:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sec:maven_pom_generation

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html

https://codexplo.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/gradle-to-maven-conversion-and-vice-versa/